# how to change href attribute value using jquery in ionic3

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, typescript, ionic3

iam trying to open a popup in my ionic3 project,iam getting the predefined template data from my database,by using `[innerHtml]` iam binding that template like below

```
<div class="content_a" [innerHTML]="bindingContent"></div>
```

`bindingContent` will be like this '`<a href="#"> Midhun </a>'`

now iam clicking that `Midhun` tag, ihave to open a popup in my ionic app, but when iam clicking that it is taking to the root page.

**What i have tried is below**

```
$(".content_a a").each(function (index, el) {
 $(this).css('color', companyFactoryInfo.color);
 $(this).css('text-decoration', 'none');
 $(this).click(function (event) {
   if ($(this).attr('href') == "#") {
     event.preventDefault();
      $(this).text().replace('#', '')
      $(this).attr('href',$(this).attr('href').replace('#',''))
      // Here iam coding for to show popup
    }
  })
})
```

while iam replacing the tag also it is not working, againg when i clicked on tag it is going to root page, Anyone please sought out of this problem ......, ThankYou

Comment: Why not just `$(this).attr('href','')`?

Comment: This doesn't look like correct html.